# ggplotly fails with geom_vline() with xintercept Date value

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

Trying to use `ggplotly` to graph time series data with a vertical line to indicate dates of interest.

Call fails with **Error in Ops.Date(z[[xy]], 86400000) : * not defined for "Date" objects**. I have tried unsuccessfully using both the latest CRAN and development versions of ggplot2 (as per plotly recommendation). Other SO questions (e.g., [ggplotly and geom_bar when using dates - latest version of plotly (4.7.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931705/ggplotly-and-geom-bar-when-using-dates-latest-version-of-plotly-4-7-0)) do not address my concerns.

As illustrated below with plot object `p` - both `ggplot` and `ggplotly` work as expected. However, when a geom_vline() is added to the plot in `p2`, it only works correctly in ggplot, failing when calling `ggplotly(p2)`.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2) 
library(magrittr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(from = lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 10),
                 y = rnorm(10))

p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = y)) + 
  geom_line() 
p ## plots as expected
ggplotly(p) ## plots as expected

p2 <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = lubridate::ymd("2019-01-08"), linetype = "dashed")
p2 ## plots as expected
ggplotly(p2) ##fails
```

Comment: You should probably just report this as a bug in `plotly`. As a temporary workaround, you can change date into numeric, and do the axis manually (i.e. use `scale_x_continuous` with correct breaks and labels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this using @Axeman's suggestion. In your case, you can just replace the date:

```
 lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01")
```

becomes

```
 as.numeric(lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01"))
```

Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

The pop-up window for vertical lines created via date (or POSIX*) to numeric conversions is rather blank. This is particularly valid for POSIX* applications where the exact time can often not be read off directly.

[image: numeric]

In case you need more significant pop-up content, the definition of a `text` aesthetic could be helpful (just ignore the 'unknown aesthetics' warning as it doesn't seem to apply). Then, simply specify what you want to see during mouse hover via the `tooltip` argument, ie. rule out `xintercept`, and you're all set.

```
p2 = p + 
  geom_vline(
    aes(
      xintercept = as.numeric(lubridate::ymd("2019-01-08"))
      , text = "date: 2019-01-08"
    )
    , linetype = "dashed"
  )

ggplotly(p2, tooltip = c("x", "y", "text"))
```

[image: date]